# Sum a cell based on unique value and unique date using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data dump in Excel that consists of monthly crew member hours worked data. Currently, there are multiple rows of data for the same date.

I want to run a macro that keeps unique names and unique dates but delete rows that have duplicated dates (keep one row for each crew member per date). In the "hours" column, I wish to combine multiple shifts from the same day into one. 
Here is my code so far and result.

```
Sub mcrCombineAndScrubDups()
For Each a In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - a.Row
        If a = a.Offset(r, 0) And a.Offset(0, 1) = a.Offset(r, 1) And a.Offset(0, 2) = a.Offset(r, 2) Then
            a.Offset(0, 6) = a.Offset(0, 6) + a.Offset(r, 6)
            a.Offset(r, 0).EntireRow.Delete
            r = r - 1
        End If
    Next r
Next a
End Sub
```

With the current code, it combines all the hours worked for the entire month into one field rather than a row for each crew member for each date. I know a pivot table can be run but my boss wants more automatic. Thanks!

[image: Result]

Comment: Please edit your Q to include sample data _as text_ (so we can copy paste it to test with. ) Also, some _before_ data would be useful

Comment: Wait a sec... For r = 1 to a larger number, and you make r = r-1 before iterating to a larger r...???  Why not `for r = lastrow to 1 Step -1` ?  I'm kind of confused by the overall nested loop... i think what you're trying to do can be accomplished with the 1 reverse stepping loop.

Comment: Additional point, do you have to modify this source file, or can you make an Overview sheet?  You could get the unique  names and unique dates, make them rows/column, respectively, then use `SumIfs` to find where both match.

Comment: Is this the same as your last question? You didn't reply the comments on those and open a new question! Exactly what Cyril said was mentioned there.